# Appcode - Pods header file does not belong to any project target

Tags: ios, appcode

Right now for me, it's a bit a pain to navigate between files with Appcode. I don't know if something is wrong with my project configuration or if it's just appcode being buggy.

I have a project "ProjectA" that is using a local pod, let's call this pod "podX". 
I want to modify a header of this pod, "headerY", from ProjectA workspace opened with Appcode.

In Appcode, when I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to search for headerY, there are always 3 results :

1. headerY (project/Pods/Headers/Private/podX)
2. headerY (podX/headerY)
3. headerY (project/Pods/Headers/Public/podX)

1) and 3) are red, 2) is normal. This is already disturbing because I don't really know which one to chose since it's supposed to be the same file. Obviously, the red indicates it's probably better to chose 2).

If I open one of the red files, (1 or 3) there's always a warning saying :

"This file does not belong to any project target, code insight features might not work properly"

And if I modify the red file, and then open 2), the modifications will not be in 2).

This is also a pain, because if I'm in the ".m" file, and I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>, to navigate to the header file, it moves me to a "red file" and not to 2).

Anyone knows how to fix this ? It's really a pain to navigate between files for me with Appcode right now.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem.